# Notation for reverse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Given a *finite* sequence with $n$ elements, is there a standard notation for the reverse of this sequence? For example,

Let $A = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ... , a_{n}).$ Then $rev(A) := 
(a_{n}, ..., a_{2}, a_{1}).$

Is this acceptable or is there a different, clearer notation? I had previously been using pythonic list notation, but I think writing this in terms of sequences would likely be better. For reference, I had been writing,

$D = [a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}]$ and $D.reverse() = [a_{n}, ..., a_{2}, a_{1}].$

Comment: I'm not aware of a *standard* notation, but you can always invent your own. For example, just $\hat{A}$.

Comment: Dunno, to me the pythonic way would be D[::-1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the sequence $B=\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $b_i=a_{(n+1)-i}$.